# Is a Heroku Java app able to access resources on external sites?

Tags: java, heroku

I've got a Java app that parses some XML located on external sites. 
From what I can tell it seems that access to any external sites will be restricted by a firewall.

> Firewalls are utilized to restrict access to systems from external
>   networks and between systems internally. By default all access is
>   denied and only explicitly allowed ports and protocols are allowed
>   based on business need.  Each system is assigned to a firewall
>   security group based on the system’s function. Security groups
>   restrict access to only the ports and protocols required for a
>   system’s specific function to mitigate risk.

Quoted from https://policy.heroku.com/security

Does anyone know if or how this limitation can be overcome? Are these "security groups" the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all accessing data on external sites from your applications.  That security policy is about how Heroku's own internal infrastructure is secured. It's not a restriction on your app.

Comment: That's good news! I was about to ask if you have had personal experience, but I see you are a bit of a Heroku guru :)